# terminal not showing up the name of user joined while I am creating a chat app after the nodemon server

Tags: node.js

I am trying to link the file index.js with the file client.js the server however gets start and also asks for the name of user who is joining . but after typing the name it is not showing the name in the terminal window.

*index.js*

`const io = require('socket.io')(8000)

```
const users = {};

 io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('new-user-joined', name =>{
        console.log("New user", name);
        users[socket.id] = name;
        socket.broadcast.emit('user-joined', name)
    });

    socket.on('send', message => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('receive', {message: message, name: users[socket.id]})
    });
})
```

`

*client.js*

`    const socket = io('http://localhost:8000')

```
 const form = document.getElementById('send-container');
 const messageInput = document.getElementById('messageInp')
 const messageContainer = document.querySelector(".container")

 const name = prompt("Enter your Name to join");
 socket.emit('new-user-joined', name);
```

[asks for name of user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXH5R.png)

[still not shows the name of user joined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNf4c.png)\

tried reloading it again again ....